# Using Qunit module setUp tearDown to test ajax

Tags: ajax, qunit, sinon

I have been finding it quite difficult to get up and running with Qunit for testing jQuery ajax.

In particular I am stumped at trying to use Qunit's module construct with a setUp and tearDown method to reduce repeated code. The following works:

```
test("ajax request is 200 OK", function () {
var xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
var requests = sinon.requests = [];

xhr.onCreate = function (request) {
    requests.push(request);
};

var callback_success = sinon.spy();
$.ajax('/course/data', { 
    success: callback_success,
});

equal(sinon.requests.length, 1);
equal(sinon.requests[0].url, "/course/data");


requests[0].respond(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, '[]');

ok(callback_success.called);
});
```

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrismcginlay/fkgoLxq0/12/) which shows a failing test (number 11). (The earlier tests I wrote as I was trying to get my head around everything).

Specifically my question is: why does the test report failure with 'requests is undefined' when I have declared `var requests;` at global scope on line 115?

Explanation gratefully received! (Edit: For some reason the JSFiddle linked shows problems with sinon.js, not evident when I run the JSFiddle from my fiddle account??)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to problem with requests being undefined in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismcginlay/fkgoLxq0/12/). My test module's setup function was never being called. For some reason I was using camelCase to define setup and teardown:

```
setUp: function () { .....},
tearDown: function() {....}
```

When of course is should be just plain

```
setup: function () {...},
teardown: function () {...}
```

So, basically a case-sensitivity error on my part, compounded with the fact that I'm finding ajax, qunit and sinon quite mind-bending.

Comment: Also note that in the newer versions of QUnit, those methods have been renamed to: `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()`!